# Android: Overlap in ExpandableListview & Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

In my android application i have an `expandableListView` and `Listview`. In `ListView` I am getting data from **Webservice**. Then data loads into `ListView` some kind of overlap between `ExpandableListView` and `ListView` Items i want to one of them is hiding under other. How can I achieve it?

Please find below the image of my application.

[image]

**My Xml code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


 <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</GridView>

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:divider="#00000000"
                android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
                android:stackFromBottom="true" >
            </ExpandableListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:divider="#00000000"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
            </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your xml code for this layout.

Comment: @Atif Farrukh i have posted my Xml code.please find above code i used

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @VenushkaT Can you tell me what kind of design need in image format.

Comment: @VenushkaT fi you need like that kind of design. i edited try it.

Comment: still it doesnt work me.ListView comes below and Expandable List view comes right above the listView still it doesnt work me.sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are using `GridView`  not `ListView` at least in this code, your `ListView` is commented currently.

Now if you want to have `ExpandalbleListView` below `ListView` add

> android:layout_below="@id/listView1"

to your `ListView`. You are using `RelativeLayout` and this layout create as `z-axis` making it possible to overlap view over each other. So, in `RelativeLayout` you have to specify where a `view` should be positioned **with respect to** other `views.